# My Notification Channel is not being created

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Whenever I send a notification through fcm.

It says it will use the default from manifest or the android app, I also have mentioned my channel in manifest as default.
It just says that the channel is not created by the app.

Log says

```
W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel requested (message_notification) has not been created by the app. Manifest configuration, or default, value will be used.
```

This is my onMessageReceived function.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(p0)
        sound=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+":/ /"+applicationContext.packageName+"/"+R.raw.alert)
        Log.d("notofiction Nul", sound.toString())

        if(p0.notification!=null){

            val title = p0.data["title"]
            val message = p0.data["body"]
            Log.d("notottg",title+message)
            buildNotificationChannel()
 if(buildNotificationChannel()){
                generateNotification(title!!,message!!)
            }

        }
        else{
            val title = p0.data["title"]
            val message = p0.data["body"]
            Log.d("notottg",title+message)
            buildNotificationChannel()

            if(buildNotificationChannel()){
                generateNotification(title!!,message!!)
            }

        }


    }
```

This is my createNotificationChannel function

```
 private fun buildNotificationChannel():Boolean {


        /*var audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .build()
        sound=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+"://"+applicationContext.packageName+"/"+R.raw.alert)
        Log.d("notisound",sound.toString())*/
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val CHANNEL_ID =  "merchant_notification"
            val CHANNEL_NAME = "Merchant Notification"
            var notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
                vibrationPattern=longArrayOf(400, 400, 400, 400, 500, 400, 400, 400, 400)
                enableVibration(true)
            }
            notificationManager= getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)





            //notificationChannel.setSound(sound,audioAttributes)

        }
        return true

    }
```

And this is my generateNotification function

```
fun generateNotification(title: String, message: String) {

        val intent = Intent(this@CustomMessagingService, MainActActivity::class.java)
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this@CustomMessagingService, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "merchant_notification")
        var audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .build()
        sound=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+"://"+applicationContext.packageName+"/"+R.raw.alert)
        Log.d("notisound",sound.toString())

        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(sound)

        notification = builder.build()
        Log.d("notot", notification.toString() + "   " + sound.toString())
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            var nb: Notification.Builder = Notification.Builder(this)
            nb.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound, audioAttributes)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()
            notification = nb.notification
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification)
        }


    }
```

My Manifest Code

```
  <service android:name=".classes.CustomMessagingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"
                    />

            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="merchant_notification" />
```

Comment: Just a thinking - maybe the making cahnnel function is not finsihed when you already call the notification generate function. You can try put them both in the same function, to make sure they occure cortectly, one after the other finished. Also, post your Manifest

Comment: I did what you said..Still its not crerating channel

Comment: Can you post your Manifest?

Comment: Uploaded the manifest including the tip you gave @Avital

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more ideas... I use Java so I can't run your code, but it looks fine to me :( I upload my `onRecieve` that works fine, maybe you can compare to your code ans find the mistake. Btw, creating channel is only for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O` so this checking soud be at the begining of the metohd and should include the wholw code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // channel for notifications

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

            if (notificationManager != null) {
                List<NotificationChannel> channelList = notificationManager.getNotificationChannels();

                for (int i = 0; channelList != null && i < channelList.size(); i++)
                    notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelList.get(i).getId());
            }

            String name = getString(R.string.notification_channel_name);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.notification_channel_id), name, importance);
            
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentTitle(message.getData ().get ("myBody"))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    }
}
```

`Manifest`:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
```